# Windows 10 File History crashing when trying to restore my files

Tags: windows-10, backup, crash, file-history

My old hard drive crashed so I had to replace it with a new one. I performed a fresh install of Windows 10 in it. I have a file history backup on my external hard drive, so I connected it and set up the file history on my new Windows installation successfully. It is backing up and working as it supposed to, but when I try to restore my old files it just crashes after I select the option and it starts to loading the files.

It is not possible that it is the external hard drive's fault because I can copy all the files away from it without getting an error, I ran a `chkdsk /f` just to be safe too, no errors found. The problem is that the files are all renamed with a timestamp on them and removing all of these timestamps from my files would take forever...

Anyway, the crash produces the following log:

```
Faulting application name: FileHistory.exe, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632cf47
Faulting module name: fhshl.dll, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d7aa
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000aa64
Faulting process id: 0xffc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d241071d460c25
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\FileHistory.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\fhshl.dll
Report Id: 8b04b4f1-2b7d-454e-8c82-7dfdd8ef5789
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I'm attaching the screenshot of what happens when I try to recover my files. 
[image: Error after opening the restore files option]

Is there anyone that can help me with this?

Comment: Non-English error log is less helpful can you translate?

Comment: Done. I did the best I could, since I'm not an english native speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if you use a previous build of Windows 10, it is unable to recover files created with File History on newer builds, so after I updated my Windows 10 to the Anniversary Update, it worked again, although I have tried to recover my files in another way and did a mess... lost several files.

Microsoft could at least warn about the possibility of not being able to recover files on previous versions of Windows 10.